# Identity for the $N_{\alpha \beta}$ of a Lie algebra from Killing form

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be two roots of a general Lie algebra of rank $r$, and $e_\alpha$ and $e_\beta$ their respective eigenvectors, with
$$[e_\alpha,e_\beta]=N_{\alpha,\beta}e_{\alpha+\beta}.$$

Let the Killing form be normalised such that $$B(e_\alpha,e_\beta)=\delta_{\alpha,-\beta}.$$
How can I prove that $$N_{\alpha,\beta}=N_{-\alpha-\beta,\beta},$$
using the invariance of the Killing form?

Comment: When you say "Let the Killing form be normalised such ...", you're not actually normalising the Killing form (which is uniquely determined), but the $e_{\alpha}$'s (which so far are only defined up to scaling).

Comment: ... and I should add: even the extra condition does not define the $e_\alpha$'s uniquely; however, if we choose a system of positive roots $R^+$ and then arbitrarily choose $e_\alpha$'s for $\alpha \in R^+$, the extra condition with the Killing form fixes unique $e_{-\alpha}$'s.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prove that by computing

$$B([e_{-\alpha-\beta},e_{\beta}],e_{\alpha})$$

in two different ways; however, when I do that, I get $N_{\alpha,\beta}=\color{red}{-}N_{-\alpha-\beta,\beta}$.